# Retrieve posts by term id custom query

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query, terms

i want to retrieve custom posts using using custom query .
my taxonomy is recipe_tx and 
terms 
(Beef) , (Chicken) etc in it .

i have tried using

```
SELECT p.* FROM wp_posts p, wp_term_taxonomy tt, wp_term_relationships tr 
WHERE p.ID=tr.`object_id` 
AND tt.`term_id`=tr.`term_taxonomy_id` 
AND (p.post_type = 'recipe_cpt')
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND tt.`term_taxonomy_id` = 37
```

but no luck .

can someone help me how to get wp posts by their term_id .

if beefs id is 37 then i want to retrieve all the posts 
with `term_id = 37`

Thank's

Comment: Here is the Codex jdm2112 is referring to: [Displaying Posts Using a Custom Select Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query).  He beat me to it...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you tried using the WP_Query class?  You might find it's easier to use the built-in tools for this instead of a custom query from scratch.  Something similar to the following should work for you:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'recipe_cpt',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'recipe_tx',
    'field' => 'term_id',
    'terms' => 37
     )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

EDIT: note the `tax_query` is an array of arrays by design.  Many tax query problems are a result of missing this detail.

EDIT:  corrected `field` value typo above, replacing 'id' with 'term_id'.

Comment: how i can find posts with LIKE clause int this case ?

Comment: Note that the possible values for `field` are `term_id`, `name`, `slug` or `term_taxonomy_id`. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is answered, but if anyone is trying to achieve the same with a raw SQL query, you could try the following:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM wpiw_posts
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT object_id 
    FROM wpiw_term_relationships AS TR 
        INNER JOIN wpiw_term_taxonomy AS TT ON TR.term_taxonomy_id = TT.term_taxonomy_id
        INNER JOIN wpiw_terms AS T ON TT.term_id = T.term_id
    WHERE TT.taxonomy = 'recipe_tx' AND T.term_id = 37
)
```

The above query will get you all the posts that belong to the given taxonomy (recipe_tx) and term ID (37).

Comment: This is better because is more faster than `new WP_Query` or `get_posts()`

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old post, but I just wanted to chime in.
@jdm2112 is correct. Just use the WP_Query class. This makes sure that if the database structure is ever updated in the future, your query still works.... However, since it looks like you are looking for a raw SQL answer, this is the actual SQL that `WP_Query` would execute... at least as of WordPress 5.6. (I've adapted the SQL to your question)

```sql
SELECT * from wp_posts 
    LEFT JOIN 
        wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    WHERE 
        (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (37)) AND
        wp_posts.post_type = 'recipe_cpt' AND
        wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
```

You can get the the actual query by creating a `WP_Query` instance, then look at the `request` property like so:

```php
<?php

$args = [
    'post_type' => 'recipe_cpt',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'recipe_tx',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => 37
        ]
    ]
];
$queryObj = new WP_Query($args); 

// This will give you the actual raw SQL query
$rawSqlQuery = $queryObj->request;
```